# WP8.1: Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync Callback Option

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I'm busy developing an application that makes use of another payment app to complete a transaction. I'm able to launch the app without any issues, but I have not idea how to know whether the transaction app is finish or whether the payment was successful. Isn't there some sort of callback I can hook into, so that my app can be notified when the other one is finished?

I got some sample code which worked for WP 8, which makes use of an `UriMapperBase`, but this class is not available in WP 8.1

Any ideas? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have this in Windows 10, but there's no way to do that in the way you mentioned in Windows 8.1 - although, there's a workaround like creating a file by the payment app in public directory -and encrypt it- then check it on your client app ..

Hopefully you'll be inspired :) .

Comment: Thanks for the response. The trans app was written by another company, so I don't have the ability to change any of it's code. Looks like I'm stuck - thanks!

Comment: You have a lot of solutions I believe, If you can trigger an online event for example by RESTful API or even RSS that show you the status of the transaction ..

Comment: Sure, performing some kind of poll would work, but what happens if the user decides to cancel the transaction. How would I know to stop the polling?

Answer (score 1):

When using `Launcher.LaunchUriAsync` there is no way to know the result in Windows Phone 8.1 (only in Windows 10).

The target app may launch an Uri that your app will handle. This is probably the way you did it in Windows Phone 8, guessing by you mentioning the `UriMapperBase`.

Handling protocol activation works differently on Windows Phone 8.1, take a look at the documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh779670.aspx.

Comment: Many thanks for the response! Looks like I'll have to migrate to windows 10?

Comment: That depends. The target app has to be a Windows 10 app and support this feature and you may not be ok with cutting of 8.1 users

Comment: Igor, you are correct - this is not really an option and the transaction app was written for wp8.1

Comment: So the only way is for the payment app to call back your app using a custom protocol (the second part of my answer)

Comment: I understand - thanks! This isn't really an option for me. It's like asking twitter to add a custom protocol to call back your app :)

Comment: Then you are out of luck I guess